# If "it is a good read" is correct, is "they are good reads" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I can describe a book as "a good read." But can I describe a number of books as "good reads?"

Comment: [Related](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/the-give-that-keeps-on-gifting-the-protean-nature-of-english-words-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/)

Answer (score 4):

Your question has nothing to do with grammar: *good reads* is perfectly grammatical.

The question is whether it is idiomatic. I'm genuinely unsure of this. I think I would be more likely to say *They're all a good read*, with a distributive sense. But I would not find it odd if somebody else said *They're all good reads*.

[Side note unconnected with your question: I am guessing that you are not a native English speaker, so I want to point out an oddity of English which often misleads people. *Few books* and *A few books* denote the same thing - a small number of books - but pragmatically are very different. If you say *few* without *a*, you are emphasising how small the number is. So idiomatically *few books* means something like *not as many books as you might have thought*; as opposed to *a few books* which is neutrally *a small number of books*. 
Apologies if you knew this, and it was just a typo.]

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Your main answer exactly corresponds to my own thinking, and even if that "side note" weren't necessary for OP himself, it's a point well worth making.

Answer (score 3):

[goodreads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/) certainly thinks so.

Sure, [read](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=read) is a countable noun. If "something that is read" is a *read*, then several somethings that are read are *reads*.

[Edit: Note that the American Heritage dictionary flags this usage as informal, while other dictionaries find it unexceptional.]